# In Wordpress AMP pages, images don't load and get src="R0lGODlhAQAB..."

Tags: wordpress, image, amp-html

when pages useing AMP mode, image don't load and I get this for source "src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="" 
I use these plugins for AMP pages:

- AMP By Automattic AMP for WP
- Accelerated Mobile Pages By Ahmed Kaludi, Mohammed Kaludi
- use pagespeed_mod for server side

This is the link for a normal page that shows the images:
https://www.bidbarg.com/%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%87-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%82-%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%DB%8C/

This is the link for a AMP page that DONOT shows the images:

https://www.bidbarg.com/%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%87-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%82-%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%DB%8C/amp/

**how i can show the image in AMP pages?**

thank you

Comment: your post have featured image? because AMP by default take post featured image for thumbnail image

Comment: yes, it has featured image. however, the pictures that are not featured

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lazy Load, disable/turn it off.